# Single integer as key in firebase (Firebase array behavior)

Tags: firebase

If I insert data into `node/a/0` in firebase.

the result will treat `a` is an array `a[0]`.

The same way, if I set my data in `node/a/1` the first array will become null

```
      "a" : [ null, {
        "-J-22j_Mb59l0Ws0H9xc" : {
          "name" : "chok wee ching"
        }
      } ]
```

But it will be fine if `node/a/2`

```
      "a" : {
        "2" : {
          "-J-25xjEXUqcpsC-5LOE" : {
            "name" : "chok wee ching"
          }
        }
      }
```

my guess, firebase automatically treat single 0 and 1 as an array.
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase has no native support for arrays.  If you store an array, it really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names.

However, to help people that are storing arrays in Firebase, when you call .val() or use the REST api to read data from Firebase, if the data *looks* like an array, Firebase will render it as an array.

In particular, if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array.  It's this latter part of the heuristic that you are running into.  Your second example only sets a value for 2, not 0 and 1, so less than half of the keys have values, and therefore Firebase renders it as an object.

You can't currently change or prevent this behavior (though it's a common source of confusion so we'll likely make some tweaks here in the future).  However it's usually very easy to deal with the behavior once you understand it.  If you need further help, perhaps you can expand your question to explain what you need to accomplish and how this behavior is preventing it.

Comment: One way to work around this behavior is to add a prefix to the strings (effectively turning them into strings) or to add a key to the path which does not fit the numeric requirements (such as `"ignoreme": false`) which would effectively disable this feature.

Comment: I feel like there should be more documentation on this issue. It is a VERY confusing issue to debug.

Comment: when i export data from android sqlite to firebase, then the id of table (int autoincrement) will become the key in json firebase. This data in firebase as a backup of sqlite.But when i import from firebase to mysql those key can't become an id in mysql. I export and import to do more processing and analyze the data.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem, but actually wanted to have a numeric key array in Swift (`[Int:AnyObject]`). I've written this function to make sure to always have an array (without null values):

```
func forceArray(from: Any?) -> [Int:AnyObject] {        
    var returnArray = [Int:AnyObject]()

    if let array = from as? [String:AnyObject] {
        for (key, value) in array {
            if let key = Int(key) {
                returnArray[key] = value
            }
        }
        return returnArray
    }

    if let array = from as? [AnyObject] {
        for (key, value) in array.enumerated() {
            if !(value is NSNull) {
                returnArray[key] = value
            }
        }
        return returnArray
    }

    return returnArray
}
```

Result:

`["0":1, "1":2]` becomes: `[0:1, 1:2]`

`{"0":1, "6":2}` becomes: `[0:1, 6:2]`

`["0":1, "1": null, "2":2]` becomes: `[0:1, 2:2]`

Hope this is helpful for someone!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, storing 0 and 1 as the key will have an issue as Firebase will think it is an array.

My simple workaround is using:

```
String(format:"%03d", intValue)
```

So that the resulting key will be "000" and "001", and they can be converted back to Int with ease.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR;

Workaround for REST API: add a meaningless filter like this one `orderBy="$.key"&startAt="0"` which actually filters-out all items with negative key): https://workaround-arrays-bagohack.firebaseio.com/matchesHeuristic.json?orderBy=%22$key%22&startAt=%220%22&print=pretty

### Explanation

This is a known and unfortunate (IMHO) behaviour of Firebase, documented deep down in their support knowledge base. Quote from [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html):

> Firebase has no native support for arrays. If you store an array, it
>   really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names.
>
> `// we send this` `['hello', 'world']` 
>   `// Firebase stores this` `{0:'hello', 1: 'world'}`
>
> However, to help people that are storing arrays
>   in Firebase, when you call `.val()` or use the REST api to read data, if
>   the data looks like an array, Firebase will render it as an array.
>
> In particular, *if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of
>   the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty
>   values, then Firebase will render it as an array. This latter part is
>   important to keep in mind.
>
> You can't currently change or prevent this behavior. Hopefully
>   understanding it will make it easier to see what one can and can't do
>   when storing array-like data.

So I've set up a small repro for you. **Original data**:

```
{
  "matchesHeuristic": {
      "1": {
          "id": "foo",
          "value": "bar"
      },
      "2": {
          "id": "w",
          "value": "tf"
      }
  },
  "notMatchesHeuristic": {
      "1": {
          "id": "foo",
          "value": "bar"
      },
      "365": {
          "id": "w",
          "value": "tf"
      }
  }
}
```

As **returned by Firebase** REST API: https://workaround-arrays-bagohack.firebaseio.com/.json?print=pretty

```
{
  "matchesHeuristic" : [ null, {
    "id" : "foo",
    "value" : "bar"
  }, {
    "id" : "w",
    "value" : "tf"
  } ],
  "notMatchesHeuristic" : {
    "1" : {
      "id" : "foo",
      "value" : "bar"
    },
    "365" : {
      "id" : "w",
      "value" : "tf"
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see `matchesHeuristic` object is transformed into an array with a null value at index 0 (because it matches the heuristic defined in Firebase docs) whereas `notMatchesHeuristic` is left intact. This is especially "nice" if you have dynamic data like we do - so we don't know untill runtime if it will match heauristic or not.

### Workaround (REST API)

However this portion of the docs doesn't seem to hold:

> You can't currently change or prevent this behavior. Hopefully
>   understanding it will make it easier to see what one can and can't do
>   when storing array-like data.

You can actually workaround this by requesting items searched by key, so

- this https://workaround-arrays-bagohack.firebaseio.com/matchesHeuristic.json?print=pretty is broken
- this is intact https://workaround-arrays-bagohack.firebaseio.com/matchesHeuristic.json?orderBy=%22$key%22&startAt=%220%22&print=pretty (add a meaningless filter like this one `orderBy="$.key"&startAt="0"` which actually filters-out all items with negative key):

`{"1":{"id":"foo","value":"bar"},"2":{"id":"w","value":"tf"}}`

NB: interestingly, seems Firebase support guys don't know about thi workaround (at least they didn't suggest it when we asked them about this behavior).