# AngularFire sync not working correctly using $save

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm pulling a result set of objects from Firebase using 
`$scope.list = $firebase(ref).$asArray()` .

I then find an object in the list and update it like this:

```
var foundObject = $filter('getByFoo')($scope.list, 'bar');
var item = $scope.list.$getRecord(foundObject.$id);
item.foo = "baz";
$scope.list.$save(item).then(function() {});
```

This works fine and propagates the changes to FB.

My problem is that if two clients are offline, and each of them update a different object in the list, and then they reconnect at the same time, only the changes from one of them propagate to the other, and not vice versa.

Does anyone know why or if I'm doing something wrong here?

Edit - below is the mcve to reproduce the problem (SO strips some tags, but just put ng-app="myApp" on the html tag and ng-controller="MyController" on the body tag).

To reproduce the problem, open two separate instances of this code. Go offline. In one instance, enter the first barcode in the text box and press enter. In the other instance, enter the second barcode and press enter. Then go online. Both instances will not show the first and second barcodes as both being checked in.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

```
  <input ng-model='barcode' ng-keydown="checkGuest($event)" type='text' id='txtBarcode'  placeholder='Enter barcode'>

  <ul id='ulGuests'>
    <li ng-repeat='guest in guests'>
      <strong>{{guest.Barcode}}</strong>
      {{guest.CheckedIn}}
    </li>
  </ul>

<script>
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["firebase", 'angular.filter']);

  myApp.filter('getByBarcode', function() {
      return function(input, barcode) {
        var i=0, len=input.length;
        for (; i<len; i++) {
          if (+input[i].Barcode == +barcode) {
            return input[i];
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    });

  myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$firebase',
    function($scope, $filter, $firebase) {

      var ref = new Firebase("https://glowing-heat-7035.firebaseio.com/results/");

      $scope.guests = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

      $scope.checkGuest = function(e) {

        //LISTEN FOR RETURN KEY
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && $scope.barcode) {

            var foundGuest = $filter('getByBarcode')($scope.guests, $scope.barcode);

            var item = $scope.guests.$getRecord(foundGuest.$id);
            if (item.CheckedIn == 'Yes') {
                item.CheckedIn = 'No';
            } else {
                item.CheckedIn = 'Yes';
            }

            $scope.guests.$save(item).then(function() {

            });
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
</script>
```

Comment: To be clear, both clients connect and both seem to push their offline updates to FB - this I can see by going into FB. But only one of the clients reflects both sets of changes. Is this a bug? Should I rather be using transaction()?

Comment: It's extremely unclear what your expectation or use case is here. If two clients write to the same record, it's going to get overwritten. I'm not sure what you mean by "reflect both sets of changes". If you want to keep an audit record, you'd use push() to create a new record with each update, not overwrite the same one. Perhaps you should start with the X portion of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) and save us some time?

Comment: A list of objects is retrieved from FB onto 2 different clients all with some property (called someProp) set to false. Each client displays the list on the screen. Both clients go offline. Client 1 then updates list[0].someProp = true. Client 2 meanwhile updates list[1].someProp = true. Both clients then go online. After a few seconds, client 1 updates and shows list[0] and list[1] both having someProp == true, but client 2 still shows list[0].someProp == false and list[1].someProp == true. Checking in FB, I can see both list[0].someProp == true and list[1].someProp == true. Why is this?

Comment: Certainly a code issue or bug. Can you create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this? And also update the question with all of these details, to create a succinct and simple use case and question?

Comment: I've edited the question to include a working sample of code and instructions.

Comment: Can you retry this with AngularFire 0.9.1? You're several versions behind in a beta library. Also, Angular 1.3 is no longer in beta--currently at 1.3.9

Comment: it looks like your data is being [treated as an array](https://glowing-heat-7035.firebaseio.com/results/.json?format=export). [You cannot perform concurrent edits on numeric, sequential ids in a distributed system](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase). You'll want to prefix those with a string, or add at least one key to that path which is non-numeric to [disable  the array-like behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777112/single-integer-as-key-in-firebase-firebase-array-behavior)

Comment: Thanks Kato. I've updated my scripts to angularfire/0.9.1/angularfire.min.js and /angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js and I think I've changed the format of the data to what you requested, but it's still exhibiting the same behaviour. (Note, the FB path is now just [https://glowing-heat-7035.firebaseio.com/](https://glowing-heat-7035.firebaseio.com/) ). You can see the data at [https://glowing-heat-7035.firebaseio.com/.json?format=export](https://glowing-heat-7035.firebaseio.com/.json?format=export) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69291/discussion-between-quijames-and-kato).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug that was corrected in the latest release (I could repro this in 2.0.4, but not in 2.1.1).